# How can I create a print function in SharePoint 2010 that resizes the output by a percentage?

Tags: 2010, printing

This is my first post in the SharePoint Stack Exchange forum. I am not a SharePoint developer but I am an authorized content manager. I've been working on a problem with our local developer and it's not a problem worth devoting a lot of the developer's time to (i.e. finding a solution  only benefits a select group of users and isn't going to take priority over a host of other things any time soon.)

Put simply, is there a way to create a button that prints the contents of a SharePoint window but specifies the size in percentage of the output of the print job?

Some background details.

In SharePoint 2003 we had a hard-coded button to print the contents of a page and the printout was used as a label for physical items in our inventory. Since upgrading to SharePoint 2010 the button stopped working. The developer's fix was to remove the button and direct users to the print command built into the browser. However when the contents are printed they are at approximately 50% of the size of the page. This is too small to be legible. The users have been using the browser print preview feature to open the content in a new window and then manually resizing the output before printing.

Purchasing an extension or off the shelf add on won't be approved so this would have to be implemented in SharePoint it's self. This issue has been going on for some time and I've looked online for an answer but found none. A search of the forum found [one article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19132/add-printer-friendly-functionality-to-sharepoint-2010/19135#19135) but it didn't solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Could try CSS3 media queries. Add media queries in a css file and use the browser print.

Ex:

```
/* style sheet for "A4" printing */
@media print and (width: 21cm) and (height: 29.7cm) {
     @page {
        margin: 2cm;
     }
}
/* style sheet for "letter" printing */
@media print and (width: 8.5in) and (height: 11in) {
    @page {
        margin: 1in;
    }
}

/* A4 Landscape*/
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    margin: 10%;
}
```

Comment: A belated thank you for your reply. I couldn't make sense of the parameters because they were A4. I showed this to my developer and he said he'd give it a try.